# How to do animations with React and Immutable.js?

Tags: animation, reactjs, immutability, immutable.js

I have a carousel that takes a state of `{pages: [...], currentPage: 0}`. If I set `currentPage = 1` I want the carousel to slide left. The same thing should happen if I increase the number again, and it should slide right I decrease it.

I can't work out how this should be done with immutable data. The animation shouldn't be represented in the state object (should it?), but storing a property on the React component removes its "pure" functional nature.

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Are you doing the animations with CSS?

Comment: In this case I could, but I'm interested in knowing how it would work when animating with JS

Comment: Did you at least search for [`[reactjs] animation`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breactjs%5D+animation) before?

Comment: what animation api? jQuery? element.animate()?

Answer (score 1):

#### Just show me an example

This doesn't use Immutable.js, but the `current` property is just a number, which is immutable in JS, so in some regards it's the same idea:

http://jsbin.com/ligejacolo/edit?js,output

#### IMO the best option is ReactCSSTransitionGroup

+1 for the unnecessarily snarky reference to [ReactCSSTransitionGroup](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) in the comments, if you can use that.

#### After that, let the browser manage state via CSS transitions

I would store the `pages` and `currentPage` as props, regardless of whether the values are Immutable.js instances (props are a stateful part of your UI, just like state, don't let the name fool you!). When they're stored as props, it provides a useful API to the users of your component.

If you're using CSS transitions then at any given moment you should be able to render the markup and classes based on this information.

For example, given the (over-simplified markup):

```
<div class=container>
  <!-- set the class to something like "inner pane2" to go to the second pane -->
  <div class=inner>
    <span class=pane>...</span>
    <span class=pane>...</span>
    <span class=pane>...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And some CSS like:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.pane {
  width: 100px;
}

.inner.pane2 {
  left: -100px;
}

.inner.pane3 {
  left: -200px;
}
```

The browser takes care of mid-transition changes to the properties.

Often times you'll need to know when the animation is done, which you can accomplish with a `transitionend` listener and `isAnimating` flag (which I would store in the state, not the props). Set `isAnimating` when `currentPage` changes and clear it on `transitionend`.

You'll also often need to know which direction you're transitioning, which you can accomplish with a `previousPage` prop.

#### Finally, if you're just using JavaScript

Keep a reference to the current transition in the `state` (possibly the jQuery selection used to start the animation, if that's what you're using). When the transition is done, remove the reference. If the `currentPage` changes mid-transition, call [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) on the selection (or whatever API you're using).

Comment: Thanks! I'd really like to know how this situation would work when animating with Javascript

Comment: ah well shoot. i'll try to expand on the answer to get into that, but it'll make my approach less clean.